# Dynamically scheduling background jobs evenly according to number of objects

Tags: ruby, scheduled-tasks, background-process

In a Sinatra app I need to run on a daily basis a job in the background (I will probably use sidekiq for this) for each User of the app.

I'd like to distribute them evenly during the day according to the number of users. So, for instance if there are 12 users the job has to be executed once every two hour and if there are 240 users the job has to be executed every 6 minutes.

I understand there are some gems that allow you to schedule background jobs (Rufus scheduler, Whenever ...), however I'm not sure they allow to change the internal a job must be executed according to dynamic values such as the number of objects in a collection.

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://tysmith.me/post/20878111254/dynamictasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever), you could get started like this:

In your user model, after a user is added successfully:

```
every (1440/User.all.count).to_i.minutes do
  add your background command task
end
```

Also don't forget to update the whenever store which actually updates the cron.

```
system 'bundle exec whenever --update-crontab store'
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't like to use callbacks (not sure even they are available in Sinatra). My current idea (don't have time right now to test it) is to have a daily scheduler job that fetch the users and according to their number schedules the actual background process using  sidekiq ```delay_for```.

Comment: It doesn't have to be precise at the millisecond. It is ok with me if having 4 users and the first job runs at 12:00.01, the second at 06:00.04, the third at 11:59:57 and the forth at 06:00:54. Thanks

Comment: Since anyway I need to run the job for a new user only the day after it's creation I could update the frequency not after the user is carpeted but once at midnight every day